# How to construct a calendar of the current year

Tags: python

I need to construct a calendar of the current year, however I do not need to show it. The only things I would like to do with it is, tell me what day of the week a random day is, if it's christmas, in March or December, also if its a tuesday in March or December. The random number is inputed by the user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With a little research you can answer this by yourself, if you like at time and datetime and so on. Read through the help and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Is this "random day" going to be a number from 1 to 366?

Comment: and @javex I am currently reading through the help and will try to come up with a more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> datetime.date(2012, 12, 25).weekday()
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to become intimately familiar with the datetime module: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

You can use `datetime.today()` to get the current date which includes the year. The attributes of a datetime object make it easy to get the year, month, and day. The timedelta class can be used to add a number of days to the beginning of a year.

The only part of your problem that can't be solved directly by the datetime module is figuring out the holidays. You'll need to have your own way of checking each holiday to see if the date matches.